# Hide one serie's dataLabel on Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a a chart with 5 series...(one serie are column and the other 4 are a line with a constant value) my problem is: I only want to show dataLabels in one of those series... and I tried activate/deactivate dataLabels but I only can do it for all series not for one of them. Can anyone help me?

Another solution for my problem would be erase all those 4 series and create a plotLine for each serie, but... how can I deactivate/activate that line with mouse click?

Thanks you all in advance :)

Comment: in the series you want to hide the labels for, can you not just set `dataLabels = { enabled: false; }`?

Comment: Ok, you're right! I didn't know that I could change that property inside the serie. Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 4):

As TZHX said, I can do

```
series: [{
            name: "Price",
            type:'column',
            dataLabels: false,
            data: JSON.parse(data_str)
        }]
```

Thanks you so much.